# How can I disable the Dropzone after uploading 1 image and enable again when I push a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I want to disable the dropzone after uploading 1 file and enable it after clicking a button

disable the dropzone after uploading 1 file

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" disabled="true"></form>
```

Button that enable the dropzone

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling it I replace the currently uploaded file with the new upload or new dropped file

```
const _dropZone = $("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
      maxFiles: 1,
      uploadMultiple: false,
      init: function () {
        this.on("addedfile", function () {
          if (this.files[1] != null) {
            this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
          }
        });
      },
    });
```

Comment: `addedfile` fires when a file is dropped on to the control, not when the upload occurs.